# Using a constant throughput timer on a group of API calls

Tags: jmeter

I am new to apache jmeter, and i am trying to set up a performance test.

I have 2 api call to tests, and my main difficulty is that those two calls should be linked, with no delay between them.
When I am using constant throughput timer (to simulate my number of calls/minutes) in addition to the duration of my test, jmeter is creating 'pauses' between my 2 api calls :

Request 1   2023-12-18 15:31:**14**.867
Request 2   2023-12-18 15:31:**20**.807
Request 1   2023-12-18 15:31:**26**.790
Request 2   2023-12-18 15:31:**32**.790
Jmeter imposes a 6s pause between each call, what I need if a delay between 2 "Request 1" calls, and not between each calls.

I would like Request 1 & 2 to be linked, but I don't know how to do that. They are in the same thread group, I also tried to use a transaction controller without success. What should I use to get this working ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this scenario is supported with built-in components or existing [plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)

You can set the desired throughput by calculating [pacing](https://www.loadview-testing.com/blog/load-testing-think-time-pacing-and-delays/) - the time to "sleep" before the next iteration. It can be done using [JSR223 PostProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) to

1. get 1st and 2nd request execution time
2. compare it with the time to delay between iterations to reach the target throughput and calculate the delta if needed
3. add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler and configure it to sleep for the "delta" from step 2